# ProgresBar не отображается в CardView

Tags: java, android, progress-bar, cardview

Есть `RecyclerView`, в нем `CardViews`, при получении данных с апишки я сетаю данные в `CardView`, также я получаю ссылку на картинку в интернете, которую загружаю с помощью *Picasso* в `ImageView`. Я хотел отображать `ProgresBar`  пока картинка из сети подгружается в `CardView`, но `ProgresBar` не отображается.

Разметка:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/progressBarCardAlbum"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:visibility="invisible" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/albumImage"
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/line" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/albumName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@color/line" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/albumDescription"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="2" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Код адаптера где все происходит:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ItemViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Album album = getItem(position);
    holder.progressBarCardAlbum.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
    holder.progressBarCardAlbum.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);
    holder.albumName.setText(album.getTitle());
    if (album.getDescription() != null) {
        holder.albumDescription.setText(album.getDescription());
    }
    Picasso.with(context).load(album.getSizes().get(0).getSrc()).into(holder.albumImage);
    holder.progressBarCardAlbum.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);
}

public static class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView albumName, albumDescription;
    ImageView albumImage;
    ProgressBar progressBarCardAlbum;

    ItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        progressBarCardAlbum = (ProgressBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.progressBarCardAlbum);
        albumName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.albumName);
        albumDescription = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.albumDescription);
        albumImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.albumImage);
    }
}
```

Comment: без GONE  тоже не работает

Comment: Хорошо,жду ответ)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас немного неправильное понимание порядка исполнения кода. Сейчас это выглядит так:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ItemViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Album album = getItem(position);

    //показываем прогрессбар
    holder.progressBarCardAlbum.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);

    //скрываем прогрессбар вместе с выделенным на него пространством
    holder.progressBarCardAlbum.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);

    //устанавливаем текст
    holder.albumName.setText(album.getTitle());
    if (album.getDescription() != null) {
        holder.albumDescription.setText(album.getDescription());
    }

    //отправляем АСИНХРОННЫЙ запрос
    Picasso.with(context).load(album.getSizes().get(0).getSrc()).into(holder.albumImage);

    //скрываем прогрессбар, но место выделенное под него все ещё видно
    holder.progressBarCardAlbum.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);
}
```

Следуя вашей логике можно переписать метод таким образом:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ItemViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Album album = getItem(position);

    //показываем прогрессбар
    holder.progressBarCardAlbum.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);

    //устанавливаем текст
    holder.albumName.setText(album.getTitle());
    if (album.getDescription() != null) {
        holder.albumDescription.setText(album.getDescription());
    }

    //отправляем асинхронный запрос и отслеживаем момент окончания загрузки
    Picasso.with(context)
            .load(album.getSizes().get(0).getSrc())
            .into(holder.albumImage, new Callback(){

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                        //скрываем прогрессбар
                        holder.progressBarCardAlbum.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError() {
                        //скрываем прогрессбар
                        holder.progressBarCardAlbum.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);
                    }
            });
}
```

В первом случае вы прятали прогрессбар, не дождавшись окончания загрузки, так как загрузка в *Picasso* выполняется в другом потоке (при данной конструкции) - это обусловлено тем, что работа с сетью запрещена из UI-потока. Во втором же прогрессбар будет скрываться в момент окончания загрузки, или возникновения ошибки.